# I miss Microsoft Pinball. Is it available for Windows Vista or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backwards-compatibility, windows-vista, microsoft-pinball

Am I the only one who misses Microsoft Pinball?  Will the XP version work on Windows Vista or Windows 7?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a copy of Windows XP lying around, you can simply copy the "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\pinball" folder in its entirety to anywhere on your Windows 7 machine and run pinball.exe. No compatibility mode needed.

This is very easy if you have Windows XP Mode installed. I just tested this on my Windows 7 x64 machine and it works great. Don't bother with third party clones.

Comment: so why did Microsoft get rid of it?

Comment: @wizlog Most likely because it is an aging game, and they released a whole new batch of modern games for Windows Vista. Same idea why we still don't have Reversi http://members.chello.at/theodor.lauppert/games/reversi/rev16_2.png

Comment: Although according this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPnehDhGa14#t=504s reversi also works in Windows 7

Comment: Reversi?

What is Reversi?

(sry, I really don't want to Google anything today)

Comment: @wizlog: Reversi is also known as [Othello](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2389/othello), a board game where the goal is to fill the board with as many of your pieces as possible.

Comment: I can't find my copy of XP... Is Microsoft Pinball still under copyright?  ex.  can my friend send it to me without thinking about its legality?

Comment: Just install Windows XP Mode if you have 7 Professional or better. I don't work at Microsoft's legal department, I can't tell you.

Comment: This is why is was removed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/18/10378851.aspx  Basically it was too buggy to port to Windows XP 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

Well, for what it's worth... http://mspinball.weebly.com/

I've not tried it or anything, and really don't plan to, but there it is. One of those "at your own risk" deals.

Comment: I'd also like to note, while I totally get why sites like lmgtfy are not permitted... This site *was* the first result on Google for the search "pinball windows 7".

Comment: ? not permitted to do what? I didn't go to the site... when you say "at your own risk"... I back-off real quick.

Comment: @wizlog by "at your own risk" I meant that I had not personally downloaded and tested the software. If you want it, you'd have to try it out yourself. Also, as with any download on the internet whatsoever, it can't hurt to have a decent virus scanner scan it.

Comment: This download can go wrong on so many levels..

Comment: this works! scanned it with AVG and its all good :) the memories <3

Comment: This link no longer works.